# Asset on view blade not working after adding prefix route on laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-10

i got some troubles with laravel 10
my asset() function not working after i add prefix on my routes

View Code

[image]

Route Code

[image]

Public Folder Structure

[image]

its normal if i didnt use the prefix, did i do something wrong?
any help would be really appreciate

im expecting the asset will be showed up, but the asset() function seems not working. it didnt show localhost url

[image]

Edit
this is when i commented the route

[image]

Route

[image]

Comment: `asset()` works as expected. Why are you passing empty strings to the asset function? The grouping on the route is for matching with the incoming request URI. It has nothing to do with your asset function.

Comment: when i put empty asset() without the prefix route, it showed the localhost url and it work normally, but when i put the prefix back, the asset not working like before

and for the grouping route, yaa i opened the matching url

Comment: Please do not post text as images, you should use the code tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your assest path inside `asset()` helper function. In your case it would become something like

```
<script src"asset('admin/assets/js/core/popper.min.js')"></script>
<script src"asset('admin/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js')"></script>
<script src"asset('admin/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js')"></script>
<script src"asset('admin/assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js')"></script>
```

Secondly, if you are bundling you assets with `vite` in Laravel 10 then you assets need to be properly defined in your `vite.config.js` file. To load these assets in you blade you have to use `@vite` helper in your. For example

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js', 'vendor/courier/build')
```

For reference I am adding the link of [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#configuring-vite)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use asset() function. And because is PHP in HTML, you need to put the file path in brackets `{{ asset ('//file path') }}` as Blade recommend.

You will have

```
<script src"{{ asset('admin/assets/js/core popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src"{{ asset('admin/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src"{{ asset('admin/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src"{{ asset('admin/assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js') }}"></script>
```